# What are the alternatives to create json object in python?

Tags: python, json, object

I want to evaluate various options to create a json object.

The code will dynamically fetch data from various sites and create json object adhering to schema given to me by designer. The challenge is - I would not know how many sites would return the data and which elements could be populated by the data returned by some of the sites.

The example is as follows: 
site X : { org : { date : dd/mm/yy, name : value } } 
here - site 1 might return the value or may not respond at all. 
site 2 might return date and name without org information.

Which python library can help me with this?

Comment: You can use the built-in `json` library to convert a string representing JSON data into a python `dict`, and then you can manually examine that `dict` however you need to fit your specific use case. Without being a lot more specific about your case, we can't really help you further than that

Comment: Either you need to already know each site's data format, or you have to depend on the site using a self-documenting discoverable format, like (yuck) XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`requests` is the right tool for that, use [response's json](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content) representation. Example from docs:

```
import requests

>>> r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/events')
>>> r.json()
[{u'repository': {u'open_issues': 0, u'url': 'https://github.com/...
```

Comment: The question isn't _How do I fetch data from a site?_, it is _How do I make sense of data that I fetched from a site?_

Comment: I generally agree, but want to point out that Requests leans on std lib: https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/master/requests/compat.py#L28

Comment: Not sure, if I am following you. I have to consume data from various location/sites (may be database or other APIs), then construct and API which will consolidate all this information and send out as single API.

Consider a social media API which extracts all your videos or posts from facebook and youtube, then sends it out in single api. Here I have to construct the JSON to be published on the fly - so how do I do that.

Comment: Are we talking about a server here? Do you want collect-convert-serve API or collect-convert-send trigger? Whatever your answer is, requests is The library for collecting part; converting business logic should be done with core Python